# Filter only the value that is below another specific value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

According to this example value in cell `A1`:

```
Boston Red Sox
1,94
Qui., 24 De Jun. 20:10


Valor Total
0.42915000
Pagamento
0.35682072
Probabilidades Totais
3,65

Adicionar 2 apostas ao meu Boletim de Apostas
Entrar
Registrar
```

I need to clear this data to only the value that is below `Probabilidades Totais`, in this case the value is this:

```
3,65
```

I've already tried using `TRANSPOSE` and `SPLIT`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,"
"))
```

To create a separate data column and `QUERY` to try to set `Probabilidades Totais` as the title of a "table" and fetch the first value below it, but it didn't work.

How could I manage to separate this value in the best possible way?

**Note: I will need to use it to analyze texts like this on several different lines in `Column A`, so I should look for an option that can also be used as `ARRAY` so I don't need to put a different formula on each line.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"Prob[^\d,]+([\d,]+)")`

If this returns an error, change the first comma to a semicolon:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"Prob[^\d,]+([\d,]+)")`

If you need the value of the extracted number to work as a number and not a string,
wrap the formula in `VALUE( )`:

`=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"Prob[^\d,]+([\d,]+)"))`

(again, being sure to change the first comma to a semicolon if you are in a locale that requires that).